# Mount disk from launch daemon on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, mount, launchd, tmp

i am trying to mount /private/tmp as ram disk. I have this "ramfs.sh" script, which i found from the internet:

```
#!/bin/bash
ramfs_size_mb=1024
mount_point=/private/tmp

ramfs_size_sectors=$((${ramfs_size_mb}*1024*1024/512))
ramdisk_dev=`hdid -nomount ram://${ramfs_size_sectors}`
newfs_hfs -v 'Volatile HD' ${ramdisk_dev}
mkdir -p ${mount_point}
mount -o noatime -t hfs ${ramdisk_dev} ${mount_point}
chown root:wheel ${mount_point}
chmod 1777 ${mount_point}
```

It is **working** fine, if i **run it manually** from terminal. However i have problem running it from LaunchDemon. I have this contents in the file "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.kalugin.ramfs-for-db.plist":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.kalugin.ramfs-for-db</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/var/root/ramfs.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/ramfs_for_db.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/ramfs_for_db_error.log</string>
        <key>Debug</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

After system load i have:

```
/dev/disk1
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:                            Volatile HD            *1.1 GB     disk1
```

But "mount" doesn't show /private/tmp as mounted on disk1. Logs show only this: "Initialized /dev/rdisk1 as a 1024 MB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume".

So definitely script is executed during system start up, but looks like mount command does not work. Any ideas? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I added some "echo" in script and make "mount" verbose. Here is output:

```
Creating ram disk...
Initialized /dev/rdisk1 as a 1024 MB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume
Mounting ram disk...
/dev/disk1 on /private/tmp (hfs, local, noatime)
Setting permissions...
```

So looks like script is doing fine, and even mounted disk. But looks like during boot "tmp" folder is overwritten?

**EDIT2**

Looks like everything is fine, except something unmounts my mounted disk on system start up.
Also someone noticed this behavior too [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6762038?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by following plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>com.local.ramdisk</string>
                <key>Program</key>
                <string>/usr/libexec/ramdisk.sh</string>
                <key>RunAtLoad</key>
                <true/>
                 <key>KeepAlive</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>PathState</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>/private/tmp/ram</key>
                                <false/>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
                <key>StandardOutPath</key>
                <string>/var/log/ramdisk.log</string>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

Looks like "RunAtLoad" is not enough or it doesn't work, i don't know. But with "KeepAlive" it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

I note you are trying to mount your RAMdisk at `/private/tmp`. I can't point to any concrete evidence, but that is just not a good idea as `/tmp` is a *system* directory. I would make a directory under `/tmp`, like `/tmp/RAMdisk` or even at the filesystem root in `/RAMDisk`.

**Original Answer**

I think the problem is that `/sbin` is not in your PATH, so the script can't find `mount`. Try adding this as the second line of your script:

```
export PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
```

Likewise the `TYPE` is missing, which indicates that no filesystem was created on your disk, i.e. that `news_hfs` failed to run, and that too, is located in `/sbin`.

Comment: That helps! Thank you. Does "PATH" differ during system startup and when user is logged in? I mean that "sbin" is already in my "PATH", when i am logged in, and i don't type it in .bash_profile.

Comment: Yes, typically the PATH differs for each and every user, and often also for interactive vs non-interactive shells. Remember also that launch daemons from `/Library` run as *system* services not as your user so they don't execute your profile.

Comment: Thanks, but for me it strange, that "sbin" (that must be system binaries) not in $PATH for launchd proccess.

Comment: `sbin` is for *statically linked binaries* that are needed during system startup before dynamic libraries on other, as yet unmounted, filesystems are available. I don't know why `/sbin` is not in the PATH for `launchd` - I guess it is because you are at liberty to add them yourself if required.

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't work anymore. I don't change anything, but now it stopped working.

Comment: I will try to do it. I know that it is system, but is just a directory with temporary files.

Comment: So i mounted it in "/private/tmp/ramfs" and still the same. When i boot up my computer, inside "/private/tmp" there was my folder "ramfs", but "mount" command don't show this folder as ram disk, it is just usual folder. So looks like mount command not working. It is working, but result of it is blocked?

Comment: Try adding `echo $? >> yourLogFile` after each of the commands to get the exit status logged - zero means success.